# publishing Grails plugins

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I'm trying to follow the [new process](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/FAO-Plugin-Authors-Important-changes-to-plugin-publication-td4469544.html) for publishing Grails plugins. I've installed the latest version of the release plugin by adding the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
plugins {
    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion", ":release:1.0.1") {
        export = false
    }
}
```

But when I try and execute the `publish-plugin` script, it tells me no such command exists:

```
c:\workspace\grails-flash-helper>grails publish-plugin
| Script 'PublishPlugin' not found, did you mean:
   1) ListPlugins_
   2) ListPluginUpdates
   3) PluginInfo_
   4) InstallPlugin
   5) UninstallPlugin
```

The source code of the plugin is [here](http://code.google.com/p/grails-flash-helper/), in case anyone wants to take a look.

Answer (score 16):

That simply means the plugin hasn't been installed yet. Run `grails compile` or `grails refresh-dependencies` first.

BTW, to follow the [new mechanism for publishing plugins](http://grails.github.com/grails-howtos/en/migrateToTheNewCentralRepository.html), you need to use version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (or 2.0.0 when that's released) of the Release plugin. Version 1.0.1 won't work.

Comment: confirmed to be the correct solution for release plugin version 2+